# Why after upgrading to Xcode 4.2 does MKAnnotation display a warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

In Xcode 4.1 there was no problem, but upgrading  to Xcode 4.2 I get the following warning:

```
Property 'title' 'copy' attribute does not match the property inherited from 'MKAnnotation'
Property 'subtitle' 'copy' attribute does not match the property inherited from 'MKAnnotation'
```

My code:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *subtitle;  
    NSString *title; 
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title; 

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;

@end
```

Comment: Those two properties after the @end, are they really in your code? And if so, why?

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Change it to:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
```

The `MKAnnotation` protocol declares

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

You shouldn't change the storage type of a property, the only change you can / should make is from `readonly` to `readwrite` if needed;

Comment: Hi @hypercrypt, I have made this changes but still it showing me same warning for 19 times! the declarations are at_property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *title; and at_property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *subtitle; I am using iOS 5.1. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try converting you application to ARC using `Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC`