# MKAnnotation: title in iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, title, ios5, mkannotation

I have a warning in my custom class for the MKAnnotation.

In iOS 5.0, apple add a new **readonly** property, the title in the MKAnnotation class, but I already have this property in my custom MKAnnotation.

Then, how can I set the title in the MKAnnotation?

Interest link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

And here is my code for iOS less than 5.0:

```
// in MyMKAnnotation.h
@interface MyMKAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 
{
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;


// in MyMKAnnotation.m
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title:(NSString *)_title localizacion:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)_localizacion
{
    coordinate = _localizacion;
    title = _title;               //-----------> here is taking the warning

    return self;
}
```

Than you!! :)

Comment: This has been already answered before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760081/why-upgrade-xcode-4-2-mkannotation-display-warning

Comment: MyMKAnnotation.h declare NSString *title; and @synthesize in .m file so that's solve your problem

Comment: @Lefteris True! sorry for duplicate answer, I didnt found it. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Lefteris help, I write this code:

```
// if the iOS version is lesser than 5.0, its retain, otherwise its copy
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __IPHONE_5_0
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
#else
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
#endif
```

Thank you very much!! :)

BASED IN: [Why after upgrading to Xcode 4.2 does MKAnnotation display a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760081/why-upgrade-xcode-4-2-mkannotation-display-warning)