# Property title Copy attribute does not match property inherited from MKAnnotation

Tags: properties, copy, title

These are the lines that are invoking a warning:
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Title; 
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Subtitle;

My Warning is:property 'title' 'copy' attribute does not match the property inherited from 'MKAnnotation'

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>



@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    int listIndex;
}

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Title; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Subtitle; 
@property (nonatomic) int listIndex;

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why after upgrading to Xcode 4.2 does MKAnnotation display a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760081/why-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-2-does-mkannotation-display-a-warning)

Answer (score 31):

Change:

> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Title;

into:

> @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;